# Words overlapping when auto linefeeding

Tags: css

I use google's prettyprint to style my code, but find some overlaps

[image]

the html,

```
<pre class="prettyprint linenums prettyprinted">
<li class="L1">
Out[24]: <django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_forward_many_to_many_manager.<locals>.ManyRelatedManager at 0x111d03748>
<li>
</pre>
```

the css

```
pre {
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 0.5;
}
```

If I reset `line-height: 1.2`, the problem solved but the entire code become too more sparse,

[image]

It seems to treat the auto linefeeding as one line.

How to solve the problem but keep the line height.

add `white-space:pre-wrap`

[image]
[image]

Comment: What happens if you remove the `line-height` altogether?

Comment: It will take `line-height: 1.42857143;` from bootstrap.css @SamHolmes

Comment: Try adding `white-space: pre-wrap` to the `pre` element? If that doesn't work, try adding it to the `.prettyprint` class instead. You want it to take priority over Google's style. Let me know if this works so I can make it an actual answer!

Comment: ok, I am trying, posted the image . @SamHolmes

Comment: Could you modify just the `line-height` of the `<li>` element?

Comment: Yes, it works. that's my problem. I intend to intense the code by decreasing the line height. @SamHolmes

Comment: I found the problem is the padding of `<code>`, could you please transmit the commit to answer for further reference.  @SamHolmes

Comment: Please just copy your comments to answer, I will upvotes and accepted, thank you  very much for your assistance. @SamHolmes

Comment: On StackOverflow, it's encouraged that if you are able to solve the problem yourself, you make and accept your own answer with the solution you used! It helps future readers know exactly what you did :)